# Test multiple lines of codes w.r.t same Exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a code segment like shown below. Each line of code throw same exception. However, in practice, when first line throws an exception, testFoo finishes its job and does not continue, as expected. But, I want a bit more different thing; since they are throwing same exception, I want to continue and check these three lines w.r.t the exception which they all throw. If they throw, test should be continue.

How can I test these three line w.r.t same exception?

```
  @test
   void testFoo(){

       assertNull( /*errorMessage*/, ClassFoo.foo(null));    // foo will throw `AssertionError` due to null parameter
       assertNull( /*errorMessage*/, ClassBar.bar(null));    // foo will throw `AssertionError` due to null parameter
       assertNull( /*errorMessage*/, ClassGbr.gbr(null));   // foo will throw `AssertionError` due to null parameter
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just catch the exception yourself:

```
@Test
void testFoo() {
    boolean fooHasThrownException = false;
    boolean barHasThrownException = false;
    boolean gbrHasThrownException = false;

    try {
        ClassFoo.foo(null);
        fail();
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        fooHasThrownException = true;
    }

    try {
        ClassBar.bar(null);
        fail();
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        barHasThrownException = true;
    }

    try {
        ClassGbr.gbr(null);
        fail();
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        gbrHasThrownException = true;
    }

    assertThat(true, equalTo(fooHasThrownException),
                     equalTo(barHasThrownException),
                     equalTo(gbrHasThrownException));
}
```

Note that your `assertNull()` is redundant. If a method throws an exception, it will not return anything.

On the side, this is a very weird scenario to be testing. If a method throws an exception, it just seems more logical to stop any further processing, if those processes down the line are going to also throw exceptions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> > I have tried to implement precondition for each parameters to a method with Java built-in Assert.assertTrue...

This is not built into java, this is from junit: `void junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(...)`. You are confusing [Java Assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) with Junit assertions.

Junit assertions should be used in your unit tests. They look like `Assert.assertEquals(result, "expected result");` They are intended to test the validity of the methods under test in your unit tests.

Java assertions should be used when verifying assumptions. They look like `assert param!=null:"param should not be null!";` They are part of the java language and can be turned on and off at compile time. They are intended to double check assumptions in your code and to produce zero overhead when turned off.

Programming with assertions is a great thing. Using Junit assertions outside of unit tests is dubious.

Comment: You are right I am confused with. Howverw, thanks to you, I have started to read the documents. Thanks. I have a question; This statement throws `AssertionError`. Is it possible to test multiple lines of test codes w.r.t `AssertionError`? I mean, say "test those 20 line in my JUnit test code w.r.t `AssertionError`, if this error is thrown, continue to execute other test codes.

Comment: When you run a collection of Junit tests each will be evaluated individually, meaning that If the first one fails with a nasty exception the remaining 99 will still get executed.

Comment: I have updated the post, ( thanks to your help ). I wonder, in test class, both line will throw `AssertionError`. If first one throw, the second `assertNull` is not executed. Both statement is throwing same exception. Can I say to JUnit "execute both assertNull statement, and dont break the test code because my expected exception is thrown from both" ?

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of this question is that you are expecting an AssertFailedError in your unit test and this is meant to be part of this test. If that is the case, you can use the following junit method structure:

```
@Test(expected = AssertFailedError.class)
public void testFoo() throws AssertFailedError
{
  assertNotNull(null);
}
```

You can use this when you are testing a block of code that you know will throw an exception.